# How to select from attribute divided by commas

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have this selector:

```
<div class="filterMenu">
<label data-id="5"></label>
<label data-id="2"></label>
</div>

<div class="galeria">
<div data-categories="5,2"></div>

<div data-categories="2,6"></div>
</div>
```

This is how I'm trying

```
$('.filterMenu label').on('click', function () {
            var id = $(this).data('id');
            $('.galeria > div').hide();
            $('.galeria > div').each(function () {
                var gid = String($(this).data('categories'));
                var gidt = gid.split(',');
                for ( var i = 0; i < gidt.length; i++) {
                    if ( gidt[i] == gid ) {
                        $(this).show();
                    }
                }
            });
        });
```

But it won't filter properly,

Any idea?

Comment: If you change the attributes to `data-categories="[2,6]"` you'll get it back as an array, and things are much much simpler.

Comment: And you probably want something more like `$('[data-id="'+ gid +'"]').show();`

Comment: @Toni Michel Caubet you could reduce your code's line by as jai has answered as well  i have

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should your code not be:

```js
if (gidt[i] == id) {
  $(this).show();
}
```

instead of:

```js
if (gidt[i] == gid) {
  $(this).show();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like this:

```
$('.filterMenu label').on('click', function () {
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    $('.galeria > div').hide();
    $('.galeria > div[data-categories*="'+id+'"]').show();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Try this
var gid = $(this).attr('data-categories');
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a spelling issue with the id check, but you can simplify it to

```js
var $galerias = $('.galeria > div');
$('.filterMenu label').on('click', function() {
  var id = $(this).data('id') + '';
  $galerias.each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var gidt = ($this.data('categories') + '').split(',');
    $this.toggle(gidt.indexOf(id) > -1);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="filterMenu">
  <label data-id="5">5</label>
  <label data-id="2">2</label>
</div>
<hr />
<div class="galeria">
  <div data-categories="5,2">5,2</div>
  <div data-categories="2,6">2,6</div>
  <div data-categories="6">6</div>
  <div data-categories="5">5</div>
  <div data-categories="2">2</div>
  <div data-categories="2,5,6">2,5,6</div>
</div>
```

---

Or

```js
var $galerias = $('.galeria > div');
$('.filterMenu label').on('click', function() {
  var id = $(this).data('id');
  $galerias.each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var gidt = $this.data('categories');
    $this.toggle(gidt.indexOf(id) > -1);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="filterMenu">
  <label data-id="5">5</label>
  <label data-id="2">2</label>
</div>
<hr />
<div class="galeria">
  <div data-categories="[5,2]">5,2</div>
  <div data-categories="[2,6]">2,6</div>
  <div data-categories="[6]">6</div>
  <div data-categories="[5]">5</div>
  <div data-categories="[2]">2</div>
  <div data-categories="[2,5,6]">2,5,6</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can make your code very easier with as @jai said i have tried like this

```js
$('.filterMenu label').on('click', function () {
   $('.galeria div').hide()
   $('.galeria div[data-categories*="'+ $(this).data('id') +'"]').show();
});
```